# Алгоритм поиска полностью совпадающих строк в нескольких файлах

Tags: delphi, строки, алгоритм, файлы

Желательно на Делфи.
Есть несколько файлов(более двух), в которых нужно провести сравнение, и вывести список совпадающих строк. при чем нужен список строк, найденных хотя бы в двух файлах, и список файлов, в которых найдена данная строка

Пример:

```
Файл 1:
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd

Файл 2:
aaa
xxx
yyy
zzz

Файл 3:
aaa
bbb
rrr

Результаты:
aaa - Файл1,Файл2,Файл3
bbb - Файл1, Файл3
```

Пытался сам написать, но под вечер моск не соображает уже...
Буду благодарен любым идеям.

Comment: 1. Для каждого файла - строим массив со всеми его строками
2. Мёрджим массивы со счётчиком

Answer (score 1, accepted):

второй раз подряд отвечаю на свой вопрос) ответ приходит, как только спрошу.

Вот такой алгоритм - в один TStringList собираю текст из всех файлов, сортирую, удаляю дубликаты;

Далее пускаю цикл по строкам этого стринглиста, и ищу данную строку в каждом файле(предварительно загрузив его в стринглист, отсортировав, удалив дубликаты).
При нахождении более одного совпедения(более чем в одном файле) по окончании проверки наличия данной строки в файлах, вывожу строку и список файлов в результирующий мемо.

А вот и сам код:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var all,f1,f2,result:TStringList;
i,j,l,m,n:integer;
resstr:string;
rescount:integer;
begin
rescount:=0;
all:=TStringList.Create;
f1:=TStringList.Create;
f2:=TStringList.Create;
result:=TStringList.Create;
all.Sorted:=true;
all.Duplicates:=dupIgnore;
f1.Sorted:=True;
f1.Duplicates:=dupIgnore;
for n := 0 to memo1.Lines.Count-1 do
begin
  f1.LoadFromFile(memo1.Lines[n]);
  all.AddStrings(f1);
end;

for j := 0 to all.Count-1 do
begin
for I := 0 to memo1.Lines.Count-1 do
  begin
    f1.LoadFromFile(memo1.Lines[i]);
    if (f1.IndexOf(all.Strings[j])>-1) then
    begin
      resstr:=resstr+'  '+extractfilename(memo1.Lines[i]);
      inc(rescount);
    end;
  end;
if rescount>1 then
  result.Add(all.Strings[j]+'  '+resstr);
resstr:='';
rescount:=0;
end;
memo2.Lines.AddStrings(result);
end;
```

</code>

Answer (score 2):

Вац алгоритм будет долго работать на больших объёмах данных. Лучше использовать хэш функцию для строк, а потом работать с массивами чисел.

Comment: Вот правильное замечание. Еще замечу, что закачивать в память файлы целиком **очень нехорошо**.

Естественно в памяти надо хранить только хэши и связанную с ними компактную информацию (файл, смещение). Читать и сравнивать только при совпадении хэша.

Для большей эффективности можно сделать в памяти кэш в который будут помещаться строки с совпадающим хэшем.

Comment: хорошо сказано, но ни про хеш, ни про загрузку файла по частям я не имею ни какого понятия))